# Use of repeated numerical prefixes for substituents on methane

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

Take trichloromethane for example. Is its preferred IUPAC name:

> 1,1,1-trichloromethane

or simply

> trichloromethane

And which is that rule in IUPAC that governs this naming? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [*Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry: IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013*](https://doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069),

> **P-14.3.4.2** The locant '1' is omitted in substituted mononuclear parent hydrides.

For the compound $\ce{CHCl3}$ (chloroform), the parent hydride is methane, which is mononuclear. Hence the locant '1' should be omitted in the preferred IUPAC name (PIN); it is simply *trichloromethane*.